# how to build multiple visual studio targets in team city

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using the "visual studio (.sln)" builder in teamcity 6.0, I would like to compile both the "debug" and "release" configuration targets. can I do it using a single builder so I dont repeat myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In teamcity build steps try this.

In both build steps use the same solution. It's a crap but there isn't any better.

buildstep0

runner type : msbuild

Command line parameters: /p:Configuration=Debug

buildstep1

runner type : msbuild

Command line parameters: /p:Configuration=Release

Comment: Will this work? Setting /P in Command line parameters usually causes this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218486/teamcity-says-to-use-build-parameters-instead-of-property-in-an-msbuild-st

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new target in csproj that then calls to Release and Debug

Comment: I don't think so - you'd have to edit the csproj manually, but it should be fairly simple

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would really meet your needs as far as not repeating yourself goes, but you could have two build steps in the build configuration. One for each of Release and Debug.