# Setting build configuration to staging

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

Simple question. How do I set the build configuration to something other than Debug?

Setting `/P:Configuration=Staging` in the Command line parameters box, leads to this error:

[TeamCity says to use "Build Parameters" instead of "/property:" in an MSBuild step. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218486/teamcity-says-to-use-build-parameters-instead-of-property-in-an-msbuild-st)

So how is it done? I need to build MSDeploy packages for all configurations, I can get the packages to build but everything is Debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you're doing it is fine -- although perhaps use a lowercase `/p:`. Our team does it this way too. TeamCity isn't throwing an error, it's just trying to provide some helpful information.

JetBrains provides some [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration) for its preferred method at the bottom of the page under `Using System Properties in Build Scripts`.